# Posting message to user's wall from C# server app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are having a problem with the review of our app which needs FB user's authorization to publish a post to his wall (publish_actions permission rejected by FB reviewer). The post is a promo offer developed by some retail store which is generated on server and needs to be put on user's wall.

We are seeing this  in many cases by apps that are approved by FB but the reviewer has stated this: 'Make sure the user message area is not pre-filled in any way by the app otherwise the submission will be rejected. This includes hashtags, URLs, and any other text not written by the user.’

What we see in many cases is that the message is pre-filled with text from a publisher so that when its posted to the wall you see an image with some text including a link to the FB page of the publisher. Does anyone know why we are not allowed to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Prefilling is not allowed. It does not matter if you see it in another App, it´s still not allowed. If you believe an App does it, report it to Facebook.

Also, the user profile is not a place to advertise, each and every single post to the user wall must be written and authorized by the user. You can only add a link with Open Graph tags to it. See the docs for information about all the possible parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#publish

Comment: So if it appears to user like this [link](http://s18.postimg.org/qxccn6dtl/HWF5.png) does that mean it is a prefilling and that should not be allowed?

Comment: if the user did not write the message text, then it´s not allowed. not sure what´s unclear about it.